# heroku: "Write Access Revoked" (10k limit) and Connection Refused

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, heroku

I'm ok with having write access refused (I have gone over the 10k rows limit), I just need to read data in my database from my web app. The site is at africanawikic.herokuapp.com.

For some reason, connections to the db are refused. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

```
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {'default': dj_database_url.config(
    default='postgres://postgres:mypassword@localhost:5432/africanawiki_geodata')}
```

Answer (score 0):

needed to promote the db using heroku pg:promote [DB_URL]